# How to update field in model connected via foreign key

Tags: python, django, forms, view, django-class-based-views

I'm working on update view where I want to update size of tshirt by click on the item on Order view list. I stacked in point where I can only display name of item but not update size of tshirt. This is django 3.

Please some hint, how I can update size of tshirt connected by foreign key with Order model.

models.py

```
class Size(models.TextChoices):
    SMALL = 'S', 'Small'
    MEDIUM = 'M', 'Medium'
    LARGE = 'L', 'Large'


class Tshirt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Size.choices, default=Size.MEDIUM)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    nr = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Tshirt, related_name='order_tshirts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def get_update_size_url(self):
        return reverse('size_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
path('update/<int:pk>/', TshirtSizeUpdateView.as_view(), name='size_update'),
```

views.py

```
class TshirtSizeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'size_update.html'
    fields = ['item']
    success_url = '/'
```

forms.py

````
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```


update template
```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="Update">
    </form>
```
````

Comment: please show your template

Comment: @ha-neul please check my edit

Comment: Your template is not for update. Did you paste a wrong one?

Comment: In addition please show your create view and create template

Comment: @ha-neul fixed, yes, that was a list template. There is no CreateView, I managed this by admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use formset for this case.

in forms.py

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

TshirtFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Order, Tshirt, fields=('name', 'size')
)
```

in views.py

```
class OrderUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    fields = ["nr", "item", "send_date"]

    template_name = 'size_update.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        
        context = super(OrderUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context["tshirt_form"] = TshirtFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context["tshirt_form"] = TshirtFormset(instance=self.object)

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        tshirt_form = context["tshirt_form"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if tshirt_form.is_valid():
            tshirt_form.instance = self.object
            tshirt_form.save()
        return super(OrderUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

in your template, put both your order form and your tshirt formset.

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <h2>T-shirt detail</h2>
    {{ tshirt_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```